# Google API re-formatting my Blogger posting

Tags: iframe, blogger, reformatting

I am developing a program that generates a blog post on my behalf. For the most part, this works fine but my problem comes when I embed a Youtube video using an iframe.

For some reason, my html is rewritten. i.e. the closing iframe tag is moved to the end of the post followed by a closing div.

Initially, I figured that I was concatenating the various fragments of my post incorrectly but when I debugged, everything was in the correct order.

Here is what I actually insert:

```
<div>
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, font-size: large;">
In this video, I am going to show you how to format a post for blogger. You can read the transcript below.
<br/><br/></span>
</div>
<h2>HTML Player</h2>
<div>
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/68p_LKet2Kw&quot; width="560"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Transcript</h2>
Sadly, my html is being re-written for some reason.
<br/><br/>
</div>
<div>
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, font-size: large;">See you soon.<br/></span>
<br/>
</div>
```

And this is what is generated in Blogger:

```
<div>
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, font-size: large;">
In this video, I am going to show you how to format a post for blogger. You can read the transcript below.
<br />
</span>
</div>
<h2>HTML Player</h2>
<div>
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/68p_LKet2Kw&quot; width="560">
</div>
<div>
<h2>Transcript</h2>
Sadly, my html is being re-written for some reason.
<br/><br/>
</div>
<div>
<span style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, font-size: large;'>
See you soon.
<br/><br/>
</span>
<br/>
</div>
</iframe></div>
```

Notice how the closing iframe tag has moved and that an additional closing div has been appended.

And here is my code:

```
            service = new Service("blogger", Applicationname);
            credentials = new GDataCredentials(Username, Password);
            service.Credentials = credentials;
            GDataGAuthRequestFactory bRequest = (GDataGAuthRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory;
            bRequest.AccountType = "GOOGLE";
            AtomEntry newPost = new AtomEntry();
            newPost.Title.Text = _Entry.Title;
            newPost.Content = new AtomContent();              
            BlogContent += BlogSectionTopic;
            BlogContent += "<h2>HTML Player</h2>";
            BlogContent += BlogSectionHtmlEmbed;                                
            BlogContent += "<div>";
            BlogContent += "<h2>Transcript</h2>";
            BlogContent += _BlogBody;
            BlogContent += "<br/>";
            BlogContent += "<br/>";
            BlogContent += "</div>";
            newPost.Content.Content = BlogContent;
            newPost.Content.Type = "xhtml";
            newPost.Updated = DateTime.Now;
            newPost.Published = DateTime.Now;
            Uri blogFeedUri = null;
            foreach (var category in categories.Split(','))
            {
                newPost.Categories.Add(new AtomCategory(category,new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#")));
            }
            newPost.Categories.Add(new AtomCategory("Video", new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#")));

            string tmpURI = GetPostingURI(service, "http://www.philipstirpe.co.uk/feeds/posts/default");

            if (tmpURI != "")
            {
                blogFeedUri = new Uri(tmpURI);
                 createdEntry = service.Insert(blogFeedUri, newPost);
            }
```

Many thanks for any answers and help.

Comment: Please use the codeblock formatting (indent 4 spaces, use the `{}` button in editor or ctrl-K) instead of entity-encoded `&lt;tag&gt;` soup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip laalto. That looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I finally discovered that I had mistakenly set the content type of the AtomEntry to "xhtml" rather than "html".